# Unexpected '<' getting issue in magento 2 shipping information

Tags: magento2

```
   Url: XXXXXXXXXXX/rest/V1/carts/16/shipping-information 
        {
     "addressInformation": {
         "billingAddress": {
            "city": "noida",
            "company": "iprag",
            "email": "nkn@gmail.com",
            "firstname": "Manish",
            "lastname": "Kumar",
            "postcode": "335001",
            "region": "UP",
            "street": ["D-84"],
            "telephone": "9413433217"
        },
        "shippingAddress": {
            "city": "noida",
            "company": "iprag",
            "email": "nkn@gmail.com",
            "firstname": "Manish",
            "lastname": "Kumar",
            "postcode": "335001",
            "region": "UP",
            "street": ["D-84"],
            "telephone": "9413433217"
          },
           "shippingCarrierCode": "flatrate",
          "shippingMethodCode": "flatrate"
        }
    }
```

Hi developing react-native sample application.
I am adding to cart items after! I don't  know how to call address and how to place the order. Please give me anyone brief explain.

Comment: this would help you https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-intro.html

Comment: hi could you give me explain breif if it is possible

Comment: Sure what is the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: like what mentioned title that issue was facing

Comment: When are you getting this error

Comment: when i was check in postman like giving the body in postman after getting error like unexpected token issue